# Two Indicator Panes in Tradingview from one Pine Script Code

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to figure out a way to merge two or more oscillator indicators in one pine script in such a way so that the oscillator indicators can be plotted in different panes. If there is such a solution or function available in Pine Script to do so, please let me know the code. Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the scales will be compatible. Then the method also depends on if you know the max and min possible values of the indicators.

See [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another) for more information regarding the implementation.